# Get data from dynamic ngmodel in Angular 8

Tags: angular, angular8

I am loading a dynamic form in Angular 8 using data I receive from my backend service.

Since the ngModel is dynamic, how do I retrieve the values from these text boxes, if I want to update the data

**Response json**

```
[
   {
      "custom_name":"Roll Number",
      "data":"3232",
      "id":"15"
   },
   {
      "custom_name":"Marks",
      "data":"75",
      "id":"16"
   }
]
```

**component.html code**

```
<div class="form-row">
   <div
      class="col-md-4 form-group"
      *ngFor="let data of result; let i = index"
      >
      <label
         >{{ data.custom_name }}
      <span class="mandatory" *ngIf="mandatory">&#42;</span></label
         >
      <input
      type="text"
      class="form-control"
      name="field-{{ i }}"
      [(ngModel)]="data.data"
      />
   </div>
</div>
```

Comment: not sure I understand the question. you have two way data binding, the data.data should be updated anytime input value changes

Comment: As @ihorbond said, all the values will be automatically updated in the `result` array in their respective objects because of 2-way binding. You don't need to explicitely bind any listeners to the `input` element. To query the updated values, just use the `result` array.

Answer (score 0):

Based from the json data, you need to bind `custom_name` like this

```
[(ngModel)]="data.custom_name"
```